# Apache Camel - Execute a task immediately before polling consumer

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to create a route that polls a folder for files that match a given regex. The route is intended to batch pickup files from the folder. Since, the move of the files into the folder isn't atomic I need to call a DB sproc before the route polls for control flow reasons. So basically in the jdsl route builder, instead of this:

```
configure(){
    from("fileURI").processor(_dbUpdater).to(endpoint);
}
```

I need something like this:

```
configure(){
    processor(_dbUpdater).from("fileURI").to(endpoint)
}
```

I know that this obviously doesn't work but is what I'm trying to do even possible? Can you execute a task immediately before the polling consumer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by adding a direct endpoint as *from* endpoint at the start of the flow. So your route would look something like :-

from("direct:a").processor(_dbUpdater).to("fileURI").to(endpoint)

You can read more about the camel direct endpoint @ http://camel.apache.org/direct.html the official camel site.

Comment: Can you continuously poll with this design? Also .to("fileURI") would act as a consumer?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Camel Component and implement a ScheduledPollConsumer implementation of consumer in it. This will make it poll continously.

poll()

Write the logic to read all files from the location specified by you and that match your regex.

Once read, You can invoke your batching logic in the poll method of the consumer here.

Thereafter, add the batch to the Exchange object.

If your component's prefix is comp and location to read is c:/readlocation then your camel route will look like this.

```
 from("comp:c:/readlocation").to("endpoint")
```